# Angular host component height won't expand based on child height in IE11

Tags: html, css, angular, sass

Visually, here is my problem. The first picture is the desired view - Chrome loads this fine. The blue is located inside the light grey color.

[image]

The second picture is how IE loads it. It might be a little hard to tell from the picture, but the blue section flows outside of the light grey area. This is not what I want - it needs to be inside. I've tried adding simple divs with different heights, but no matter what, I cannot get the grey area to expand based on the contents inside it in IE11.

[image]

Parent component:

HTML: `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`

CSS:

```
:host(.parent) {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: stretch;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    flex: 1;
    padding: 0 1rem;

    @media #{$medium-up} {
       flex-direction: row;
       padding: 0 40px;
    }
}
```

Child Component:

HTML:

```
<div class="test">
  <form [formGroup]="formGroup" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit($event, formGroup.value)" class="form-content">
    <div class="sections">
      <div class="section">
        <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="welcomeTemplate"></ng-container>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
:host(.child) {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: stretch;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    flex: 1;
    padding: 1rem;
    background-color: $color-background-light;
}

.test {
    background-color: blue;
    color: white;
}
```

If anyone has suggestions, they would be much appreciated. I've been trying to figure this out for a little bit now and I can't get anything to work.